# Rebuild XML using lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to build a new XML file based on another XML using lxml in Python.

Let's say I have an original XML file (test_db.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test_Database Version="1.0">
 <Song FilePath="resources/test.mp3" FileSize="8911899">
  <Tags Author="YourMother" Title="Test" Genre="Singalongs" Album="Stupid Songs" />
  <Comment>4B - 6</Comment>
 </Song>
</Test_Database>
```

I'm using the following to parse the file and save the info in a model. I'd then like to modify the info and save it as a separate XML.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("resources/test_db.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# Get main dict tag that contains all the tracks
main_dict = root.findall('Song')
self.data = main_dict
```

Desired XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test_Database Version="1.0">
 <Song FilePath="resources/test.mp3" FileSize="8911899">
  <Tags Author="YourFather" Title="NewTest" Genre="Singalongs" Album="Stupid Songs" />
  <Comment>4B - 6</Comment>
 </Song>
</Test_Database>
```

I've been looking through the lxml documentation, and tried working through some tutorials, but they all seem to require building the XML from strings. I don't need to use strings because I have the actual element already. Shouldn't I just be able to add the Song element as a sub element of root and write to a file? I can't seem to find how to do that.

What I've tried:

```
root = ET.Element("root")
for obj in self.data:
    root.append(obj)
    print(ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

This printed everything as a single bytestring rather than a tiered xml

```
root = ET.Element("root")
for obj in self.data:
    child = ET.SubElement(root, obj)
print(ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

This presented an error that the argument for SubElement must be bytes or unicode.

**Is there any way to add an element as a subelement of root?**

Comment: Why is your call to `print(ET.tostring(...))` within the for loop body?

Comment: It looks like the only change you are making is in the `<Tags>` element you are changing the value of the `Title` attribute from `Test` to `NewTest`; is that true?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel That's a mistake. It didn't copy/paste properly. Should be outside the loop.

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes, in this example I'm only making 2 small changes. In the real file, there are hundreds of <Song> tags and potentially hundreds of changes. So I want to maintain the data in the model, and use the save function to write to a file from the model contents.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer No, that doesn't apply here. I'm not trying to rebuild the xml from strings, I'm trying to build it from xml elements. I'm sure I could loop through all the children of the element and create subelements from the tags, attributes, and text. But that seems stupidly unnecessary, when I already have a fully built xml element. I just need to add it to root. Yet, I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I read your other post again. Basically what SubElement does is create an element, and append it in one go. I can't use that because I already have an element, and SubElement requires bytes or string. And when I use append, it appends it as a single bytestring, not an xml. so something is lining up right.

Comment: I don't know about "real life" since I can't see it; only the sample xml in the question. So you have to make sure the xml is properly representative of "real life". In the question, I only see one change (not two, as you said), from `<Test>` to <`NewTest>`. Also, from where exactly do you get the values for this and the other hundreds of possible changes? That's also not in the question.

Comment: @JackFleeting How changes are made, and what they are is irrelevalent. There could be no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not an real answer, but using your code and `lxml.etree` directly rebuilds the XML:

```
import sys, lxml
from lxml import etree

print(sys.version)
print(lxml.__version__)

xml = etree.parse('/tmp/test_db.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

# Get main dict tag that contains all the tracks
main_dict = root.findall('Song')

# create new root
root2 = etree.Element('root2')

# Add genre
genre = lxml.etree.SubElement(main_dict[0], 'Genre')
genre.text = "Country"

for obj in main_dict:
    root2.append(obj)

doc = etree.ElementTree(root2)
print(
    etree.tostring(
        doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8'
    ).decode('utf-8')
)
```

Out:

```
3.7.7 (default, Oct 11 2020, 01:50:22) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)]
4.6.2
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root2><Song FilePath="resources/test.mp3" FileSize="8911899">
  <Tags Author="YourMother" Title="Test" Genre="Singalongs" Album="Stupid Songs"/>
  <Comment>4B - 6</Comment>
 <Genre>Country</Genre></Song>
</root2>
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that the bytestring that I thought was incorrect is actually the right format, but it's just not printing to console properly? Thank you for taking the extra time to show how to print properly. That's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @Chaky31: I didnt investige your code further, because it was not clear to me, what `ET` is. Both modules: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` and `from lxml.etree import ElementTree as ET` were raising errors using your code.

Comment: I forgot that piece, I'll add it to the post. I used: `from lxml import etree as ET`